# Find the interval on which the function is increasing

Tags: calculus

Find the interval on which the function $f(x) = 3 / (x^4 + 1)$ is increasing.

I draw a graph and got the answer the interval should be $(-2, 3) \cup (2, 3)$, wonder why it is not correct though?

Thanks and Sorry for not formatting the question very well.

Answer (score 1):

The function is as follows: $f(x)=\frac {3}{x^4+1}$.

Taking the derivative of $f(x) = y$ with respect to its argument x, and setting $\frac {dy}{dx}=0$, gives us information regarding where $f(x)$ reaches its local extremum/slope of $0$ (local maximum or minimum).

So find such a point where the function achieves a zero rate, or constant slope, set it's derivative to equal zero and solve for x.

Thus we have:

$$f(x)=\frac {3}{x^4+1}\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac {-12x^3}{(x^4+1)^{-2}}=0\Rightarrow x=0$$

This implies that our function $f(x)$ achieves a slope of zero at $x=0$. Plugging this value back into our original function gives a corresponding point of $(x,y)=(0,3)$.

To determine the intervals of increase and decrease, we simply create a deleted neighborhood of $f(x), s.t. x\in[-\infty,0]\cup[0,\infty].$ Test points within these intervals (into $f'(x)$), to determine whether the function is increasing or decreasing for that given bound.

Finally, we see the interval of increase is $x\in(-\infty,0]$ and the interval of decrease is $x\in[0,\infty)$. Please note the point $0$ is included in these intervals, as a slope of zero is mathematically defined as a function which both increases and decreases.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What do derivatives tell you? When is $-12x^3\geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
You have
$$
f(x) = 3\left(x^4+1\right)^{-1}
$$
so you can compute $f'(x)$ by chain rule and see where $f'(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply diffrenciate the $$ f(x) = \frac{3}{(x^4 + 1)}$$

to get $$ f^\prime(x) = \frac{-12 x^3}{(x^4 + 1)^2}$$

and for increasing conditions,  $$ f^\prime(x)>0$$

which gives you basically,
$$ x^3<0$$

thus, any $$x \in R: x<0$$
or in human languages, any Real negative number will make the function increasing.  Cheers!